# puppet 7: Deferred value in File.content impossible?

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to use a deferred value in puppet 7 (server 7.4.2 and agent 7.14.0) to write a file, like this:

```
  file { "/tmp/testfile":
    ensure => 'present',
    content => Deferred("node_decrypt", [node_encrypt("abc")]),
  }
```

But while the catalog is compiled, the server prints

```
Puppet File[/tmp/testfile]['content'] contains a Deferred value. It will be converted to the String 'Deferred({'name' => 'node_decrypt', 'arguments' => ["-...
```

The effect for the file is that it contains the text 'Deferred(...' instead of 'abc'.

Same applies to Notify.message. Did I misconfigure something? Or any clue why this does not / should not work for File.content. And if yes, what is the alternative for writing a deferred value into a file?

Comment: Are some module versions (like stdlib) relevant, here? I thought file is built-in and modules do not matter.

Comment: No solution on my side, but I get the same behavior with Deferred functions with Puppet Agent 6 and Puppet Server 6.
However, when I simplify my role to the minimum, it works fine. It must be linked to these bugs with PSON vs JSON serialization of the catalogs. https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-10928
https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-11445 The comments in these bugs point to a potential fix by removing some binary file from the catalog output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [K. Shu's hint](https://serverfault.com/questions/1109548/puppet-7-deferred-value-in-file-content-impossible?noredirect=1#comment1449053_1109548) I found the answer myself: it was caused by using the serialization format `pson`. I was using this format for puppet 4 agent compatibility. As soon as I switched to json, deferred functions started to work fine:

```
puppet agent --preferred_serialization_format=json ...
```